# Date field to be filled automatically

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I am using PostgreSQL and created the below table:

```
CREATE TABLE "TrainingMatrix"
(
  payroll text NOT NULL,
  "TrainingName" text NOT NULL,
  "Institute" text,
  "TrainingDate" date NOT NULL,
  "ExpiryDate" date,
  "RecorderName" text,
  "EnteringDate" date,
  CONSTRAINT "TrainingMatrix_pkey" PRIMARY KEY (payroll, "TrainingName", "TrainingDate")
)
```

I want to let `EnteringDate` to be filled automatically by the current date in the machine for each entered record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE "TrainingMatrix"
(
  payroll text NOT NULL,
  "TrainingName" text NOT NULL,
  "Institute" text,
  "TrainingDate" date NOT NULL,
  "ExpiryDate" date,
  "RecorderName" text,
  "EnteringDate" date NOT NULL default current_date,--"EnteringDate" date,
  CONSTRAINT "TrainingMatrix_pkey" PRIMARY KEY (payroll, "TrainingName", "TrainingDate")
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE "TrainingMatrix"
(
  payroll text NOT NULL,
  "TrainingName" text NOT NULL,
  "Institute" text,
  "TrainingDate" date NOT NULL,
  "ExpiryDate" date,
  "RecorderName" text,
  "EnteringDate" date not null default current_timestamp,
  CONSTRAINT "TrainingMatrix_pkey" PRIMARY KEY (payroll, "TrainingName", "TrainingDate")
)
```

current_timestamp is equivelent to Now() will give the current date & time (including timezone)  http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/functions-datetime.html

Defining the column as not null will also help to ensure that no records are explicitely entered that do not have a timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

use default keyword

```
column datatype default sysdate
```

Check this as well

[How to set default value for column of new created table from select statement in 11g](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5934083/how-to-set-default-value-for-column-of-new-created-table-from-select-statement-i)

Comment: There is no `sysdate` in Postgres.

Answer (score 0):

By using the default sysdate you can achive the desired output.

```
CREATE TABLE "TrainingMatrix"
(
  payroll text NOT NULL,
  "TrainingName" text NOT NULL,
  "Institute" text,
  "TrainingDate" date NOT NULL,
  "ExpiryDate" date,
  "RecorderName" text,
  "EnteringDate" date default sysdate,
  CONSTRAINT "TrainingMatrix_pkey" PRIMARY KEY (payroll, "TrainingName", "TrainingDate")
)
```

Comment: There is no `sysdate` in Postgres.